# Passing variable from function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I'm trying to take text as input from user and split into array and pass it.

```
<textarea id="texty">
</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="funky()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var str;
var array;
var ACL1;
var ACL2;
function funky() {
    str = document.getElementById('texty').value;

    array = str.split(' ');
}
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var xi = array[i];

    if (xi === "ACL") {
        ACL1 = array[i + 1];
        ACL2 = array[i + 2];
    }
}
```

I'm again using that variables ACL1 and ACL2 in some other place in the same page using this piece of code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.write(+ ACL1 + "<br>");
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.write(+ ACL2 + "<br>");
 </script>
```

Do anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "another html file" and "in the same page"

Answer (score 0):

All your funky() function does is split the string into an array and nothing more - you need to make your for loop part of funky() and see what happens.

Comment: yes, I've tried that but still I'm not able to use those values anywhere else.

Comment: Try logging (or alerting) the values of ACL1 and ACL2 in the loop.  I'm not sure that (xi === "ACL") will ever evaluate to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

You assign a value to `array` *when the button is clicked*.

You try to process that data into `ACL1` and `ACL2` and write them to the page *while the document loads*.

The button **won't** be clicked **before** the document loads.

1. Move the `for` loop inside the `funky` function
2. Get rid of your document.write scripts.
3. Replace them with div elements (or some other container that is more semantically appropriate).
4. Modify the `funky` function to add the content to the page once it is populated the variables

   1. Find the element you want to put the content in (e.g. with `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`)
   2. Put the content inside it (e.g. with `document.createTextNode` and `document.appendChild`